# Importing VTK Image Into Mayavi

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I'm having trouble importing an image read through VTK into the Mayavi pipeline.  I would like to use the Mayavi volume rendering tools to render the VTK image, but I can't figure out how to feed the image into Mayavi.  I am able to read the image without a problem:

```
from tvtk.api import tvtk
reader = tvtk.MetaImageReader() 
reader.file_name = "image.mhd"
reader.update()
```

But now I can't figure out how to get the output from the reader into Mayavi.  I'd like to use the data from the image as input to the Mayavi volume renderer, as in [this example](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_chemistry.html#example-chemistry), but I haven't been able to get the raw data from the VTK image and pipe that through to Mayavi.